# Get object from collection within collection according to filtered criteria

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have the following classes:

```
class Parent
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   List<Child> { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   List<GrandChild> { get; set; }
}

class GrandChild
{
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have one List of objects as follow:

```
// Parent list with children objects that all, also have grand children objects.
List<Parent> parent = new List<Parent>();
```

Now I want a Child object where one of its GrandChild object's name is say "John".

How do I use LINQ to acquire this, since I don't know how to return a Child object from the filtered Parent objects?

(I can use foreach loops to get my object, but isn't that why LINQ is there, to shorten the code, or is this not possible with LINQ?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I can use foreach loops to get my object, but isn't that what LINQ tries to avoid?" No, it´s what linq internally does anyway. However it just hides it away from you.

Comment: @HimBromBeere not neccessarily actually. Linq also supports lazy execution.

Comment: @MetaColon And in which way does this contradict my comment? If or if not the query is executed lazily does not have anything to do with if there´s an iteration happening.

Comment: @HimBromBeere in some way Linq does avoid the loops, as for example it wouldn't be lazy then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) to flatten the Child collections into one collection, and then filter those:

```
parent
    .SelectMany(p => p.Children)
    .Where(c => c.GrandChildren
        .Any(g => g.Name == "John"))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, what I struggled to understand from other posts. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you'd want the query in the Linq query syntax, you could use something like this:

```
from parent in parents
from child in parent.Children
where (
    from grandChild in child.Grandchildren
    where grandChild.Name == "John"
    select grandChild
).Any()
select child;
```

It's a type of taste what you prefer.